# Enable inputs from Bootstrap Checkbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to know if someone can help me, i've been trying to enable various inputs from a checkbox button of bootstrap, here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/FArMm/1031/.

**EDIT**

I found a solution, if someone ever need to do something similar, here is the code  http://jsfiddle.net/jc4QD/1/

Comment: You should share your solution as a separate answer and mark it accepted

Answer (score 2):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FArMm/1033/

You need to enclose your fields in a `<form>` tag

```
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" id="test">Activate</label>
    </div>
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="prueba" />
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="prueba" />
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="prueba" />
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="prueba" />
    </form>
```

The use the `.each()` function:

```
$('#test').click(function () {
    var checked = this.checked;
    console.log(checked);
    $('.prueba').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled', !checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: I just checked your fiddle and i still see same result, the checkbox doesn't enable the inputs.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FArMm/1038/ it seems that the problem is "data-toggle="buttons", if i remove that line works just fine, if i add it, doesn't work.

Comment: THere is yet another weird behaviour i have found, when i remove boootstrap.min.js it works as expected, what could be the reason? http://jsfiddle.net/FArMm/1039/

Comment: bootstrap.min.js does not affect this. Even if you remove it from the previous fiddle it will work.

Comment: But i still can't get the result i want, in your fiddle inside the button i can see the HTMl checkbox design,i really don't know what to do, i have tried everything without success.

Comment: you need to have inputs inside the <form> if you want the checkboxes to be seen